# Many to Many mapping problem with insert new records in child (JPA)

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using **many to many** annotation of JPA. I have 3 tables `postal_master`, `postal_mapping` and `postal_detail`. I have to insert new records in the `postal_detail` table but the entry already exists in the `postal_master` table.

Now to achieve same, I have to fetch the `id` from `postal_master` table and call the same function of `JPA` with the existing `postal_master` entity and new records for `postal_detail`. New records successfully insert in the `postal_detail` but `postal_mapping` table deletes the previous mappings of the `postal_master` entity and inserts new mappings. I want that new and previous mapping should exist in the mapping table.

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name = "dbk_postal_mapping", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = 
    "postal_master_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = 
    "postal_detail_id"))
private Set<PostalDetailEntity> postalDetails;
```

In `postal_master` table, I have `id` as the primary key and same for the `postal_detail` table. In `postal_mapping` table, `postal_master_id` and `postal_detail_id` is foreign key and combine treat as a primary key.

[image: Image to Explain the scenario]

I am not good at drawing. Please let me know if you guys don't understand the problem?

code for saving:

```
        Long postalMasterId 
=postalMasterRespository.findByCountryCodeAndPostalCode(postalMasterEntity.getCountryCode() , postalMasterEntity.getPostalCode());
            if(null != postalMasterId) {
                postalMasterEntity.setId(postalMasterId);
            }

            postalMasterRespository.save(postalMasterEntity);
```

Domain Classes:

PostalMaster:

```
    @Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "dbk_postal_master")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false, exclude = {"id", "postalDetails"})
public class PostalMasterEntity extends AuditableEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String countryCode;

    private String postalCode;

    @Column(name = "is_active")
    private Boolean active;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name = "dbk_postal_mapping", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "postal_master_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "postal_detail_id"))
    private Set<PostalDetailEntity> postalDetails;
```

PostalDetail:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
@Entity
@Table(name = "dbk_postal_detail")
public class PostalDetailEntity extends AuditableEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private Long providerId;

    private String centerCode;

    private String accessTechnology;

    private String speed;
```

AuditableEntity:

```
    @MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class AuditableEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;

    @CreatedDate
    private Date creationDate;
```

Please let me know guys how can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Add the code where you are setting the value of postal details and other entities.

Comment: I update the question with saving code. If a master entity does not exist then it is saved with a new master record. otherwise, it will update the master with new details.

Comment: Can you post you all domain class please ?

Comment: @VimitDhawan According to your picture, seems your relation will be `OnetoMany`.

Comment: you can check the post. I have added the domain classes

Comment: @VimitDhawan If no value in `postal_details` class, how `postal_mapping` got id of `postal_details` ?

Comment: I think you can look into the many to many mapping. Actually, in Postal_Master I have the list of postal detail.

Answer (score 0):

From master object get the set of postal details and add the new postal details in it. and then set it again and call save method.

Comment: I already think about this solution but I am running this code in spring batch so it will affect the performance. I don't want to fetch postal detail.

Comment: But are already fetching postal master so it will get the postal details on its own.

Comment: I just fetch the id from postal master not object

Comment: Thanks, Pooja it is one of the solutions if you want to achieve same.

Comment: what is the another solution?

Comment: I am looking for same but I believe there should be a better way to achieve the same.

Comment: you already have postalMasterEntity this object, from where you are getting this?

Comment: I have implemented a spring batch job. I read it from CSV file. So in the first chunk may be the postal master is already in DB. I just want that in next chunk if the postal master entity already in DB then new postal details should be inserted in the DB with the same postal master entity.

Comment: you are always creating a new set and then setting the postal details in it. That is why your previous values are getting overridden. You can get id and the set of details if you don't want to get the whole object.

Comment: I already have done by getting the postal master id and insert that postal master id in the new master entity with postal details that I read from CSV but still, it overrides the mapping table

Comment: yes because you are not using the already saved data of mapping table. you are always creating a new one and overriding the previous one. you are only getting id which won't work.

Comment: because I am using this functionality inside the spring batch so I don't want to fetch the postal detail every time. I just want that new postal detail to insert with mapping table by using only postal master entity.